# Whitelist IP to Port 443 after successful Login to Port X

Tags: security, port, firewall, whitelist

I have about 15 web applications running in my network but I do not want to expose them all publicly for security reasons.
My idea is to have 14 of these **applications running on port 443** and one **application on port 1** (doesnt matter).

Only **port 1 will be exposed publicly**. Once you **successfully authenticate** on the application **listening to port 1** your **IP** will be **whitelisted** for X hours and therfore you will gain access to ther other apps listening on **port 443**.

Is anybody aware of a solution that does this or do I have  to build the solution on my own from scratch?

greetz

Comment: You can basically do the same by adding an authenticating proxy like for instance Pomerium, set that to say Google authentication, and only allow an identity with your email address to be proxied. That way only you will be able to get to those applications (also on a network level), and auth will be offloaded to Google. However, all this is off-topic on SO.

Comment: Thank you this looks really interesting but I dont think that M2M connections are possible with pomerium. Another use case would be to enter the connection string into an app. The app would not know how to handle the auth.